# error : remote gerrit already exists

Tags: gerrit

I am trying to add remote gerrit but I am getting the error as :

```
fatal: remote gerrit already exists.
```

how to remove existing gerrit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't list what command was causing this error output, but I assume it was something like:

```
git remote add gerrit <url>
```

If you already have a remote named gerrit, you will get this error.  You can see what remotes are in your repository with

```
git remote -v
```

To remove a remote, use

```
git remote rm <name>
```

name is 'gerrit' in your case.

Answer (score 1):

A remote which name "gerrit" already exists. You can find it by:

`git remote -v`

So, remove this old remote:

`git remote rm gerrit`

Then add it again:

`git remote add gerrit <url>`